# VS 2015 won't break at breakpoint in web api project

Tags: wpf, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I have a VS2015 solution with 2 C# projects. A WPF client, and a Web API server. I set a breakpoint in the Web API code. Then ran the WPF client in debug. The breakpoint icons in the source file changed from solid red dots to red circles. The debugger is not breaking at the breakpoints. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively have 2 applications and you're trying to debug both at the same time which won't work.

Make your API run in IIS then use a separate Visual Studio instance to attach debugging to that process ( you can find it running under w3wp ).

So you can do this effectively with 2 instances of Visual Studio, one for the client and one for the API.

You can also simply open the same solution with a second VS, and run the API from there then have the client hit the api on the same URL as the one being debugged. It is a bit strange to use 2 Visual Studio instances but it does the job quite well.

Use whichever method you're more comfortable with.

Comment: See my comment to Jarak.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is probably because you are just debugging the client.  I had the same difficulty getting to the code of a WCF service recently.  As I understand it (and I'm no expert, so people who know better feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) basically Visual Studio won't peek into the server code while you are just debugging the client.  I presume that when you run the client, you also have the server running at the same time?

I *think* the best way to deal with this is either to start your client, and then attach the VS debugger to the server process (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx), or to run both the client and server programs at the same time when you start the debugger (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx).

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: (SO wouldn't let me post this in my answer since I'm new to the site)...  See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514135.aspx as that may be relevant to you if you are using WCF

Comment: Attaching the debugger to iisexpress.exe worked. Setting multiple startup projects in VS2015 also worked. I was not aware of this feature of VS2015. Also, debugging the web api project and starting the wpf exe from File Explorer also worked. Thanks for the help.